# azure data factory: how to merge all files of a folder into one file

Tags: json, azure, azure-data-factory

I need to create a big file, by merging multiple files scattered in several subfolders contained in an Azure Blob Storage, also a transformation needs to be done, each file contains a JSON array of a single element, so the final file, will contain an array of JSON elements.

The final purpose is to process that Big file in a Hadoop & MapReduce job.

The layout of the original files is similar to this:

```
folder
 - month-01
   - day-01
        - files...

- month-02
    - day-02
        - files...
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I did a test based on your descriptions,please follow my steps.

***My simulate data:***

`test1.json` resides in the folder: `date/day1`

[image]

`test2.json` resides in the folder: `date/day2`

[image]

`Source DataSet`,set the file format setting as `Array of Objects` and file path as `root path`.

[image]

`Sink DataSet`,set the file format setting as `Array of Objects` and file path as the file you want to store the final data.

[image]

Create `Copy Activity` and set the `Copy behavior` as `Merge Files`.

[image]

***Execution result:***

[image]

The destination of my test is still Azure Blob Storage, you could refer to this [link](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-azure/index.html) to learn about Hadoop supports Azure Blob Storage.

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I needed, previously I missed to check the merge behavior.

Comment: I made a test with some of the files and it worked OK, now I tried to merge all of the files (2M+ files, about 580MB), but only 247 files are being merged, is there an intrinsic limitation for these tasks?

Comment: any idea if this is possible to do using only dataflow? (what i mean is specifically taking a bunch of json objects and "boxing" them into a parent node). another words we start with stream1: `{"name":"alex"}`  next item in stream is: `{"name":"liza"}` the resultset iwould like would be `[{"name":"alex"},{"name":"liza"}]`

Comment: This is extremely slow for files of any significance / count