# azure data factory: iterate over millions of files

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

Previously I had a problem on how to merge several JSON files into one single file,
which I was able to resolve it with the answer of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56550727/azure-data-factory-how-to-merge-all-files-of-a-folder-into-one-file/).

At first, I tried with just some files by using wild cards in the file name in the connection section of the input dataset. But when I remove the file name, theory tells me that all of the files in all folders would be loaded recursively as I checked the copy recursively option, in the source section of the copy activity.

The problem is that when I manually trigger the pipeline after removing the file name from the input of the data set, only some of the files get loaded and the task ends successfully but only loading around 400+ files, each folder has 1M+ files, I want to create BIG csv files by merging all the small JSON files of the source (I already was able to create csv file by mapping the schemas in the copy activity).

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is probably stopping due to a timeout or out of memory exception.

One solution is to loop over the contents of the directory using

> Directory.EnumerateFiles(searchDir)

This way you can process all the files without having the list / contents of all files in memory at the same time.

Comment: Apparently, it is stopping because some of the original files have a bad JSON format, so now I need to figure out a way to fix those badly formatted files before passing them to the copy activity.