# Merging two or more files from a storage account based on a column using Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

I need to merge/concat two files which are present in my Azure Storage Account using an ADF pipeline.

There is a merge option in copy activity of azure, but this will merge similar files. The file has column with pipe separated data

My requirement is: Append the second file columns to the first file columns based on a particular ID

Example>>

```
File1
ID|Name|Age|XX|YY    
001|Abc|20|x1|y1
002|Dfg|30|x2|y2


File2
ID|AA|BB
001|a1|b1
002|a2|b2
```

Now the output of my ADF activity can be a different file or in file 1 or 2 with the below fomat

```
OutputFile
ID|Name|Age|XX|YY|AA|BB
001|Abc|20|x1|y1|a1|b1
002|Dfg|30|x2|y2|a2|b2
```

Note: the above files were combined based on ID.

How can the same be achieved using adf pipeline activity?

As mentioned earlier, have tried the merge copy activity behavior. This will not satisfy my requirements.

[azure data factory: how to merge all files of a folder into one file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56550727/azure-data-factory-how-to-merge-all-files-of-a-folder-into-one-file)

Comment: I cannot use the ADF Data Flow activity as my data base and the azure storage account has a Linked service with Self-hosted Integration runtime, which does not support
so have to go with Copy Data, but the joining those files is still a question

Comment: Can you  import them into a SQL database? Then you can run a query in Copy active and export them to a csv file to achieve that.

Comment: we dont want a database talk that is the reason we are putting it into a file. The first and Second file where data pulled from db using copy activity and written to Storage Account. The reason we dont want a db interaction due to large volume of data

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the Merge Copy functions like a UNION in SQL, so it makes since this wouldn't work for your scenario. Given the constraints you've mentioned, specifically the lack of Data Flow, you're going to have to do some custom coding somewhere. I have two ideas on how I would tackle this problem.

1. You mentioned in your comments that the original data files were pulled from SQL Server using Copy. That means (assuming they are from the same server) that you could solve the problem on the source side by writing a Stored Procedure that a) Unpivots the two tables into temp tables then b) Pivots the results into a staging table. That Staging table would then be the Source for your Copy activity. I would prefer this route because the SQL engine would be ideal for this kind of work: when all the data I'm operating on is in SQL Server, I try to put the work there as well.  Also, Stored Procedures are really easy to work with in Data Factory.

   **1a**. If you are against the Staging table concept, then your Stored Procedure could use Polybase to write the results out to Blob storage instead, in which case there would be no Copy activity in your pipeline.
2. If you must use the text files you previously produced, then an Azure Batch job with custom code to read the blobs, perform the work, and output the target blob is probably your best alternative. This would be my choice of last resort because I find Azure Batch tedious and difficult to work with, but sometimes only custom code will do.

If you end up doing something else, I'd be very curious to learn how you solve this problem.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, yes all the files were pulled from the same SQL Server.
Went with your 1st suggestion instead of StoredProcedure I combined them using common table expressions. Not sure on the performance yet as I am trying on small scale for now.
Went through ADF dint find helpful activity, yes agree with you on the 2nd point Azure Batch with custom code will be bit hectic and time consuming to come up with that.

Answer (score 0):

Though I was not able to find a solution using ADF, came up with a Common Table Expression(CTE) which will help me combine those in the db and then extract them to a file

Refer this for CTE - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cte-in-sql/