# Azure Data Factory Merge to files before inserting in to DB

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

We have two files that are ^ delimited file and a comma separated txt files which are stored in the Blob Storage like below

File1 fields are like

ItemId^Name^c1^type^count^code^Avail^status^Ready

[image]

File2 Fields are like

ItemId,Num,c2

[image]

Here the first column in both the files are the key and based on it I need to insert them in to one table on the Azure DB using the Azure Data Factory. Can anyone suggest how can this be done in the ADF. Should we merge the two files into one file before inserting into the Database.

AzureDB columns are

ItemId Name c1 type count code Avail status Ready Num c2

So it should be like

Item1  ABC(S)  1234  Toy  10  N  N/A  POOL  N/A  19  EM

Item2  DEF(S)  5678  toy  7   X  N/A  POOL  N/A   6  MP

I was referring to this [Merging two or more files from a storage account based on a column using Azure Data Factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61336401/merging-two-or-more-files-from-a-storage-account-based-on-a-column-using-azure-d) but couldnt understand if we can merge the two files before inserting in to DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the 2 files to create 2 datasets, use join activity to jointhem together and simply sink to the SQL table in a dataflow.

[image]
Here Inner join is used, you can adapt to use the type of join your preferred.

[image]
You can see the preview of the join successfully merged the 2 files/data sources.

Adjust the field mapping in Sink if needed.
[image]

Here is the arrow-separated.csv I used:

```
ItemId^Name^c1^type^count^code^Avail^status^Ready
Item1^ABC(S)^1234^Toy^10^N^N/A^POOL^N/A
Item2^DEF(S)^5678^toy^7^X^N/A^POOL^N/A
```

Here is the comma-separated.csv I used:

```
ItemId,Num,c2
Item1,19,EM
Item2,6,MP
```

Result in DB:
[image]

Comment: Hi @ray can we use join in data flow?

Comment: Certainly. As OP didn't give a definition of his merge, I am not sure a join will be useful to him though.

Comment: @ray Sorry for not being clear in my question, I have updated my question.. The only column common between the data set is ItemID based on that I need to merge them.. Should be then using the Join here.. This is my first ADF project , any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: @AllAboutBI Can you help how the join can be done here

Comment: Please check this video from mark (msft) https://youtu.be/zukwayEXRtg

Comment: @trx I have updated the answer to demonstrate how a join is used and some relevant details like field mapping.

Comment: @ray - think I accidentally downvoted this - trying to undo if you can edit answer maybe I can undo it.

Comment: @ray - done on my end too.  Sorry about that