# Handle the test file that has custom delimter

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have text file that has the custom delimiter ^ on the source text file like below

[image]

I want to insert this data from the .txt file in to the Azure SQL Server Database, how can this be handled in Azure Data Factory. On the Source Dataset I have set the Connection parameters like below

[image]

But when I try to preview the dataset it doesnot show anything

[image]

How to handle the text files with custom delimiters in ADF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like file is not pointed to in your dataset

Reference video :

https://youtu.be/-yHCaqkeJy4

Comment: What does that mean, can you please explain

Comment: In the file path, we need to point to the file..container name/directory name/file name. Use browse button to choose your file. Then try to preview

Comment: Added a reference video

Comment: Thank you for the help, it helped fixing the issue. I am very new ADF can you please suggest any ideas to this question please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69588556/azure-data-factory-merge-to-files-before-inserting-in-to-db